# SOAPMonitor unable to communicate with server

Tags: java, soap, axis

I have a problem with my Apache Axis 1.4 service, using the SOAPMonitor which comes with the binaries.

While the applet starts up with no problems (e.g. http://localhost:8080/axis/SOAPMonitor), the status bar in the embedded application gives the following error message:
"The SOAP Monitor is unable to communicate with the server"

Some further reading that I have already tried:

- http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/install.html (See appendix)
- http://ws.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#AppendixUsingTheSOAPMonitor
- http://www.javabeat.net/articles/25-programming-web-services-using-apache-axis-2.html
- http://www-scf.usc.edu/~csci571/2005Spring/axisinstall.html (see "Enabling SOAPMonitor in Axis")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After ensuring that the SOAPMonitor is actually enabled in the web.xml configuration file, I noticed that it used a port of 5001.  I used 'netstat.exe' and noted that nothing was already listening on this port but...  Changed it anyway to another unused port, 8081.
After restarting my app server once more this seemed to work.

Note that the TCPMonitor application which also comes with Axis has similar functionality and was easier to set up!